# from tagging/models.py: ImportError: cannot import name 'generic'

Tags: python, django, generics

While running server import error is generated. Here I even don't use this generic types anywhere in my file.

Then how can this error is generated???

```
C:\Python34\python.exe manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000000004BC8B70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.4.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.4.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.4.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.4.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.4.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.4.egg\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.4.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-2.0-py3.4.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tagging\models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
ImportError: cannot import name 'generic'
```

Comment: What tagging library is this? Are you sure it's conduit m compatible with recent versions of Django? ( Note, Django 2.0 was literally released only today.)

Comment: ohhh, then that might be the issue. I have django 2.0 and that's why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I had solved the error.
- In settings.py file, there is INSTALLED_APPS. I removed 'tagging'
  from that which solves all my errors.

  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tagging` library does not support Django 2.0. If you check [Django's git repo](https://github.com/django/django/tree/stable/1.9.x/django/contrib/contenttypes), you will see that there is no more `generic` module in `Django.contrib.contenttypes`. It was removed in Django 1.9. Downgrade to Django 1.8 for your library to work or, which I would recommend, use a different tagging library, preferably one that is well enough maintained to support at least Django 1.11.